# Intercepting query string parameter for a request, store the value and append to a redirect response

Tags: google-chrome

Using a Chrome extension, I need to intercept a query string parameter for request Site A, store the value and append it to a redirect from the Site A's response. Chrome is executing the original redirect versus the new redirect. Thanks for the input!

Please see below:

background.js

```
function getFromLocalStorage(key) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.storage.local.get([key], (result) => {
      resolve(result[key]);
    });
  });
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
   async function (details) {

    var queryParameter1 = url.searchParams.get('state');
    var queryParameter2 = url.searchParams.get('code');
   
    if(queryParameter1!=null)  { chrome.storage.local.set({ "interceptedParameter": queryParameter1 });}

    if(queryParameter2!= null) {
      console.log("queryParameter2: " + queryParameter2);
    
     const interceptedParameter = await getFromLocalStorage("interceptedParameter");
     const redirectUrl = "https://example.com/new-redirect-url" + "?interceptedParameter=" + interceptedParameter;
   
     console.log("Modified URL "+ redirectUrl)

      return { redirectUrl: redirectUrl };
    }

    // Continue with the request
    return { cancel: false };
  },
  { urls: ["<all_urls>"], types: ["main_frame"] },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

To append a query string parameter from the original request and append it to the redirect resposne.